# Filtering (and replacing) data in excel vba by date range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to filter data in an excel sheet by a certain date (day) range. This is how the sheet looks like by default (note: the begin and end date is specified later in the code not directly in the excel sheet):

[image]

Here's the vba user form:

[image]

The aim is to replace existing data (records) with new data bound by the begin time and end time and then choose the customer buying products by highest value in this new range.

My code for the "OK" command button looks like this for now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Table(20) As Double


  If ((TB_R_Od.Value = "") Or (TB_R_Od.Value <= 0) Or (TB_R_Do.Value = "") Or (TB_R_Do.Value <= 0) Or 
(TB_R_Od.Value > TB_R_Do.Value)) Then
MsgBox "Wybierz poprawnie zakres raportu!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Błąd zakresu"
Else
Sheets("Transakcje").Range("M3") = CDate(TB_R_Od.Value)
Sheets("Transakcje").Range("N3") = CDate(TB_R_Do.Value)
End If

Sheets("Transakcje").Range("A1:I19").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & 
Sheets("Transakcje").Range("M3"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Sheets("Transakcje").Range("M3")
For j = 0 To 20
Table(j) = Sheets("Transakcje").Cells(j + 3, 8).Value
Next j
 
 Application.WorksheetFunction.Max (Table)

For i = 0 To 20
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Table) = Sheets("Transakcje").Cells(i + 3, 8).Value Then
    TextBox3.Value = Sheets("Transakcje").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have mostly problems with the autofilter function which does not seem to be working. I'm not sure if it's the right one to use here. (note2: *TB_R_Od.Value* is the begin date *TB_R_Do.Value* is the end date).

Comment: What problems are you facing exactly?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz  I get the best customer from the default sheet which means that the only problem is with filtering the data.

Comment: Please define the problem